# Disable UIView and controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

When a user clicks on a button a popup similar to this image appears. But when i am on a slow internet, the popup takes awhile to load. so until the popup loads i need the view in the background (where the button resides) to freeze (disable) and the user should not be able to click on any controls.

How can i disable the view/control ?

Comment: Consider adding some visual indicator like UIActivityIndicator to your view while waiting for the popup to be displayed. Otherwise the user might think that the app just froze.

Answer (score 4):

See -[UIView userInteractionEnabled]

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled

Set

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

On the parent view of the controls you'd like disabled.

Comment: i guess i could write this code in the button click function. when the button is clicked the code executes and calls the popup and then disable the view by using `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
`am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it would work. In the call back after the dialog is dismissed, you can set it back to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button's enabled property to NO - if you're using UIButton or a subclass thereof.

ex.

```
[button setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
testView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: "someView.enabled" // is not a valid code in objective-c.